# Shader error in Custom/FurShaderV1: Non-square matrices not support(3x1) at line 62(on gles) UNITY

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, shader

I'm having an error which is about shader .

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced '_Object2World' with 'unity_ObjectToWorld'

Shader "Custom/FurShaderV1" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base Texture (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _FurBlend ("Base Color Cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0
    _FurTex ("Fur Texture (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _FurColor ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _FurMat ("Fur Color (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _FurShadow("Darken Lower Layers", Range(0,4)) = 1
    _CutOff ("Cut Off", Range(0,0.5)) = -0.01

    _FurLength("Fur Length", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    _Layer("Fur Layer", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    _Gravity("Gravity Strength", Range(0,-2)) = 0.0
    _Wind("Wind", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)

    [MaterialEnum(Off,0,Front,1,Back,2)] _Cull ("Cull", Int) = 2
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Cull [_Cull]
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert addshadow

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _FurTex;
    sampler2D _FurMat;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        //float4 T0; // fur alpha
        float Layer;
    };

    float _FurLength;
    float UVScale   = 1.0f;
    float _Gravity;
    float3 _Wind;
    float _Layer;

    void vert(inout appdata_full i, out Input OUT)
    {
          UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, OUT);
          //This line is responsible for creating the layers
          float3 P = i.vertex.xyz + (i.normal * _FurLength);

          //Modify our normal so it faces the correct direction for lighting if we
          //want any lighting
          //float3 normal = normalize(i.normal);

          // Couple of lines to give a swaying effect
          // Additional Gravity/Force Code
          float3 vGravity = float3(0,_Gravity,0);
          vGravity = mul(vGravity, unity_ObjectToWorld);
          float k =  pow(_Layer, 2);  // We use the pow function, so that only the tips of the hairs bend
                                     // As layer goes from 0 to 1, so by using pow(..) function it still
                                     // goes form 0 to 1, but it increases faster exponentially
          P = P + (_Wind*k + vGravity*k);


          //OUT.T0 = i.texCoordDiffuse * UVScale; // Pass long texture data
          // UVScale??  Well we scale the fur texture alpha coords so this effects the fur thickness
          // thinness, sort of stretches or shrinks the fur over the object!

          i.vertex = float4(P, 1.0f);//mul(float4(P, 1.0f), UNITY_MATRIX_MVP); // Output Vertice Position Data
         // i.normal = normal; // Output Normal
            OUT.Layer = _Layer;
    }


    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;
    float _CutOff;
    fixed4 _FurColor;
    float _FurBlend;
    float _FurShadow;

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
        fixed4 f = tex2D (_FurTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
        float Lum = ((f.r + f.g + f.b) / 3) * f.a;
        clip(Lum - (_CutOff));

        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        fixed4 FurColor = tex2D(_FurMat, IN.uv_MainTex) * _FurColor;

        if(IN.Layer < _FurBlend)
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        else
        {
            o.Albedo = (pow(IN.Layer,_FurShadow)) * FurColor.rgb;

        }

        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG
} 
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

It works actually on PC when i convert this into .exe but when i tried to convert it to android as .apk then this errors shows up. I can't find any relative questions about my problem and I have been locked up here for 3 days.

My conversion is a success but the problem here is when I open it . It is just a black screen on my phone. And I'm speculating that this error is the cause of it?

Comment: Change `float3 vGravity = float3(0,_Gravity,0)` to `float4 vGravity = float4(0,_Gravity,0,0)`

Comment: Will it work sir also on the PC???